# How to query a subselect with sorting and pageable in R2dbcRepository

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, r2dbc

I am using `R2dbcRepository` and I think it does not support native queries. `@Query(nativeQuery` is giving an error.

I cannot seem to find a solution for the query without going native since I have `join` tables, `subselect` query, and `Pageable`.

I cannot get all the results from Registration and filter it out since I have `Pageable` (unless it is achievable in flatMaps?)

Does anyone have an idea on how to turn this query into reactive?

This is my query:

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query;

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
    "select R.ID, R.REGISTRATION_DATE, R.NAME, U.FULL_NAME, R.STATUS, R.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, "
        + " (SELECT ASSESSOR.FULL_NAME FROM JHI_USER ASSESSOR WHERE ASSESSOR.USERNAME = R.LAST_MODIFIED_BY) AS LAST_MODIFIED_BY "
        + " FROM REGISTRATION R "
        + " INNER JOIN JHI_USER U ON R.ID = U.REGISTRATION_ID "
        + " WHERE U.SUBMITTED_REGISTRATION = TRUE "
        + " AND LOWER(U.FULL_NAME) LIKE like concat('%', LOWER(:fullName), '%') "
        + " order by :sortColumn :sortDirection limit :pageSize offset :pageNumber")
List<Object[]> findAllByAppUsers(@Param(value = "fullName") String fullName,
                                 @Param(value = "sortColumn") String sortColumn,
                                 @Param(value = "sortDirection") String sortDirection,
                                 @Param(value = "pageSize") int pageSize,
                                 @Param(value = "pageNumber") int pageNumber);
```

[image]

> (1) If I remove the `@Query(nativeQuery=true)` and just use
> `@Query("select...")` and return a `Flux<Object[]> findAllByAppUsers(...)`
>
> ```
> nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [42000] [42000] Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT R.ID, R.REGISTRATION_DATE, R.NAME, U. FULL_NAME AS FULL_NAME, R.STATUS, R.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,  (SELECT ASSESSOR.FULL_NAME FROM JHI_USER ASSESSOR WHERE ASSESSOR.USERNAME = R.LAST_MODIFIED_BY) AS LAST_MODIFIED_BY  FROM REGISTRATION R  INNER JOIN JHI_USER U ON R.ID = U.REGISTRATION_ID  WHERE U.SUBMITTED_REGISTRATION = TRUE  ORDER BY $1 $[*]2 LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4";
> ```
>
> (2) If I remove the parameters, I get this error:
>
> ```
> org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object
> ```
>
> (3) If I do `@Query("select new com.my.dto.RegistrationDTO () ...")`
>
> ```
> nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [42000] [42000] Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT NEW COM.[*]MY.DTO.REGISTRATIONDTO (R.ID, R.NAME, U.FULL_NAME AS FULL_NAME,  (SELECT ASSESSOR.FULL_NAME FROM JHI_USER ASSESSOR WHERE ASSESSOR.USERNAME = R.LAST_MODIFIED_BY) AS LAST_MODIFIED_BY)  FROM REGISTRATION R  INNER JOIN JHI_USER U ON R.ID = U.REGISTRATION_ID  WHERE U.SUBMITTED_REGISTRATION = TRUE";
> ```

The SQL is working fine in postgreSQL:

```
SELECT R.ID, R.REGISTRATION_DATE, R.NAME, U.FULL_NAME AS FULL_NAME, R.STATUS, R.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
(SELECT ASSESSOR.FULL_NAME FROM JHI_USER ASSESSOR WHERE ASSESSOR.USERNAME = R.LAST_MODIFIED_BY) as LAST_MODIFIED_BY
FROM REGISTRATION R
INNER JOIN JHI_USER U ON R.ID = U.REGISTRATION_ID  
WHERE U.SUBMITTED_REGISTRATION = true
AND LOWER(U.FULL_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%test%')
ORDER BY full_name, last_modified_by ASC LIMIT 10 offset 0
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace

Comment: updated to include stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of the [`Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/repository/Query.html) annotation:

> Annotation to provide SQL statements that will get used for executing the method.

A `Query` wraps a *SQL* statement, not some other language like HQL/JPQL. I don't think there are any "non-native" queries supported by `R2dbcRepository`, yet.